# b-splines for drawing, not predicting, based on control path

Tags: r, curve-fitting, spline, bspline

I've tried to approach my general problem through two separate questions here on SO: [Specify clamped knot vector in bs-call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33609538/specify-clamped-knot-vector-in-bs-call) and [Fit a B spline to a control path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33574457/fit-a-b-spline-to-a-control-path). The responses to these have led me to a reformulation of the bigger problem, which I'm now posting.

What I'm trying to accomplish is (in R), given a set of (non-monotonous) control points, how do I draw a b-spline along the path given by the control points. The b-spline must be clamped in both ends. This is purely for graphical purpose.

NOTE: I'm not trying to predict values based on the control points. Using a combination of `predict`, `lm` and `bs` as proposed in [Fit a B spline to a control path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33574457/fit-a-b-spline-to-a-control-path) results in a b spline that tries to pass through the control points (which is not the point) - especially if setting `df` or `knots` so that the spline is clamped, this approach leads to overfitting and the spline will pass through every control point.

In the end the approach will be applied to 100s or 1000s of separate sets of control points so algorithmic efficiency is a factor, though currently I'm just looking for a way to get it done.

toy data (same as in the linked questions):

```
path <- data.frame(
    x = c(3, 3.5, 4.6875, 9.625, 5.5625, 19.62109375, 33.6796875, 40.546875, 36.59375, 34.5, 33.5, 33),
    y = c(0, 1, 4, 5, 6, 8, 7, 6, 5, 2, 1, 0)
)
```

All of this is for the purpose of calculating [Hierarchical Edge Bundles](http://scholar.google.dk/scholar_url?url=http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download%3Fdoi%3D10.1.1.220.8113%26rep%3Drep1%26type%3Dpdf&hl=da&sa=X&scisig=AAGBfm2kGCn_dINd_7Sr2WjCb_CWYJZqTg&nossl=1&oi=scholarr&ved=0CB0QgAMoADAAahUKEwjLhfmZxvzIAhWG3iwKHTyBC5A) in R.

**EDIT:**

Okay, so it seems that I'm unable to access the underlying b-spline implementation that is used under the hood (Or maybe I didn't try hard enough). Anyway I ended up crafting my own Rcpp based implementation inspired by [Jason Yu-Tseh Chi](https://chi3x10.wordpress.com/2009/10/18/de-boor-algorithm-in-c/)'s de Boor algorithm. The upside of this was that I could make it vectorised so multiple paths could be constructed in one go. This will be part of an upcoming CRAN package (hierarchicalSets), but I'll be happy to share it with anyone expressing interest in the meantime (too long to post here)...

**UPDATE:**

For anyone interested in this, spline drawing will be implemented as a geom/stat extension to ggplot2 in the [ggforce](https://github.com/thomasp85/ggforce) extension package

Comment: Sounds like you want to do a B-spline fitting, but only want the spline to pass thru the first and the last point and not for other points. If this is right, you will need a constrained least square B-spline fitting algorithm (or function).

Comment: @fang I don't think we are talking about the same thing (or I might have a big misconception about b-splines). I don't want to *fit* anything, as in find the best b-spline to describe my data. I have the control points and degree and knot vector, which uniquely describe a b-spline. I simply want to draw it in R, ie extract points along the b-spline to be used for plotting. See for instance http://www.cs.mtu.edu/~shene/COURSES/cs3621/NOTES/spline/B-spline/bspline-curve.html

Comment: Since you said "drawing a b-spline along the path given by the control points", I guessed I am assuming the path is close to the control points and therefore my previous comment (In general B-spline cases the curve could be pretty far away from the control points). Anyway, since your problem is actually the basic point computation on a B-spline curve, I supposed R would provide such a function to do it. If not, google "Cox DeBoor algorithm" to find out how to compute a point on a B-spline curve given parameter t.

Comment: Yeah - I would assume R had that functionality too, but it seems everything I can find in relation to splines in R is concerned with fitting, which was the reason for my initial (slightly confusing) questions.

Comment: I would be interested in your code. Can you ping me?

Comment: @MikeWise - Sure. This might sound stupid, but how? There doesn't seem to be any contact info on SO...

Comment: Sorry. MikeWise1618 at gmail

Comment: @MikeWise - depending on your need I'll add a ggplot2 extension with the functionality. See the edit

Comment: I will certainly use it, and test it, when it is available. But I don't really need it urgently at the moment. So don't make it just for me :)

Comment: It is live on github now - might be some time before I send the package to CRAN though

Comment: Maybe worth moving your edit/updates below as an answer?